# how to hide soft keyboard in WP7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, soft-keyboard

In a TextBox input. 
After type enter key, i want to hide soft keyboard. 
How to do it in codes?

```
private void OnKeyDownHandler(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
           {
                if (e.Key != Key.Enter)
                   return;         

...}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`this.focus()`
This will allow the focus to be lost from the textbox. It basically puts the focus on the page instead. You could also convert your textbox to `read only` to disallow any further input.

Hiding the SIP can be done by simply changing the focus from the textbox to any other element on the page. It does not have to be this.focus(), it could be anyElement.focus(). As long as the element is not your textbox, the SIP should hide itself.

Comment: thanks. but i could not use it. because i only find this.SearchTxt.Focus() which means get focus. but no set focus for the TextBox.

Comment: Well, hiding the SIP can be done by simply changing the focus from the textbox to any other element on the page. It does not have to be `this.focus()`, it could be `anyElement.focus()`. As long as the element is not your textbox, the SIP should hide itself.

Comment: `this.Focus()` did not work for me. I had to create a new fake `Button` on my page with 0 width and focus that instead.

Answer (score 2):

I use the following method to dismiss the SIP:

```
/// 
/// Dismisses the SIP by focusing on an ancestor of the current element that isn't a
/// TextBox or PasswordBox.
/// 
public static void DismissSip()
{
    var focused = FocusManager.GetFocusedElement() as DependencyObject;

    if ((null != focused) && ((focused is TextBox) || (focused is PasswordBox)))
    {
        // Find the next focusable element that isn't a TextBox or PasswordBox
        // and focus it to dismiss the SIP.
        var focusable = (Control)(from d in focused.Ancestors()
                                  where
                                    !(d is TextBox) &&
                                    !(d is PasswordBox) &&
                                    d is Control
                                  select d).FirstOrDefault();
        if (null != focusable)
        {
            focusable.Focus();
        }
    }
 }
```

The `Ancestors` method comes from [LinqToVisualTree](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2010/03/linq-to-visual-tree/) by Colin Eberhardt. The code is used in conjunction with an Enter key handler, for "tabbing" to the next TextBox or PasswordBox, which is why they're skipped in the selection, but you could include them if it makes sense for you.